# Error when trying to add a column using Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a basic Transpose and Concatenate Macro.

Data is entered on an input tab, macro is run, data is displayed on an output tab.

Problem is that, one of the columns on the input tab was not set up to display on the output tab. This needed column is column E.

I have added it into the Macro, but it is displaying an error. When I click `Debug`, the word `Apply` on line 30 below is highlighted as the error, however, I do not see how that is the error.

Here is the Macro:

```
Sub TransposeConcatinate()
Dim i As Integer, toprow As Integer, lastrow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy data from the pastehere sheet to the output sheet

    Sheets("Output").Cells.Delete
    Sheets("PasteHere").Columns("A:E").Copy Sheets("Output").Columns("A:E")
    Sheets("Output").Select

'Sort the columns
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C:C" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:E" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:E")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


'Count the number of rows
    With Sheets("Output")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    toprow = 2

'Insert a column, make it a combination of ID and Price Schedule for use as a unique ID
    Columns("C:C").Insert

    For i = 2 To lastrow Step 1
        Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2)
    Next


'Do the concatination and transposing
    For i = 2 To lastrow Step 1
        If Cells(i, 3) <> Cells(i - 1, 3) Then
            toprow = i
            Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 4)
            Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i, 5)
        End If
        If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i - 1, 3) Then
            If toprow = i Then
                Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 4)
                Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i, 5)
            Else
                Cells(toprow, 6).Value = Cells(toprow, 6).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 4).Value
                Cells(toprow, 7).Value = Cells(toprow, 7).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 5).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

'Remove extra column
    Columns("C:C").Delete

'Title new columns
    Cells(1, 5).Value = "Concatinated Quantities"
    Cells(1, 6).Value = "Concatinated Prices"
    Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

'Remove unneeded rows
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 5) = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next

'Remove unneeded columns and format
    Columns("C:D").Delete
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 29
    Columns("C:D").ColumnWidth = 25
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 15


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I used this and received a Compile Error: Syntax error. Showing the Sub TransposeConcatinate() highlighted in Yellow and the last statement changed to Red: If Cells(i, 3) <> Cells(i - 1,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the actual error, it says that your sort reference is not valid, meaning your sort criteria (you key's are not valid).

You have the last key as RANGE("D:E") and you need to change it to RANGE("E:E").  You can only have a single column as a key in a sort.

Comment: You're awesome for noticing that, however, it caused a greater issue. It now combined columns B & E and not sure why

Comment: I wonder if it's because of this:    

'Remove unneeded columns and format
    Columns("C:D").Delete
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 29
    Columns("C:D").ColumnWidth = 25
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 15

Comment: Combined?  How so?  You are deleting 3 columns with COLUMNS("C:D").DELETE, but that shouldn't "combine" the columns.

Comment: When I updated the RANGE("D:E") to RANGE("E:E") and then ran the Macro, it took the data in Columns B & E from the 'Paste Here' tab, and displayed them on the 'Output' tab mixed in with each other. For example, column B on the 'Paste Here' tab are Price Schedule names and column E is the Product Name, however when the macro is run, the 'Output' tab shows some lines with the Price Schedule names and some with the Product Name, whereas I was only trying to add column E as additional Output on the Output tab. Kepping columns seperate. Maybe I should remove the Columns("C:D").Delete?

Comment: Well, deleting the statement Columns("C:D").Delete didn't help. Basically I loved the Macro the way it was, I just needed column E from the 'Paste Here' tab to display with its corresponding line/data on the 'Output' tab.

Comment: Do you have columns C & D hidden on the original tab?  Excel might be "skipping" over the hidden columns with RANGE("A:E")

Comment: I don't..  :-(   They are visible.